# Can I place an app with 1,000's of auth'ed users in sandbox mode and not lose them?

Tags: facebook

I need to make some updates to an app I developed; I have them ready to go, but I'd like to place the App in Sandbox so no one sees any hiccups. I just want to verify that I will not lose my 1000s of auth'ed users when I do this?

Comment: Create a new app. Authenticate with a few user's (not testers, developers, admins). Put the app in sandbox mode and see what happens.